# ServiceStack client get generated URL

Tags: oauth, client, servicestack

Is it possible to access the URL a service call will use before calling the service using any of the ServiceClientBase child classes?

I need to fully resolve the url before making the service call so that the URL can be included into the OAuth authorization signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IReturn extension method ToUrl with appropriate HTTP method and format strings.

Example: request.ToUrl("POST", "json") where request implements IReturn.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, For reference here's the source code for [ServiceClientBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs). If it helps, you can add a pull-request to make `GetUrl` overridable and protected, that way it can be accessed by sub classes.